# Issues in running everyauth example

Tags: node.js, everyauth

I am trying to run the everyauth example. However, it is showing the following error

```
ReferenceError: /Users/tyler/clicker/everyauth/example/views/home.jade:1
  > 1| - if (!everyauth.loggedIn)
    2|   h2 Not Authenticated
    3|   #register
    4|     a(href='/register') Register

everyauth is not defined
```

I have install everyauth. And when I do sudo node server.js to run the example,it shows the app running. However, when I visit the site at localhost:3000, it shows the above error.

It is showing something like everyauth is not defined. What could be the reason? I mean everyauth is definitely installed. Could it be that it is no imported properly?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have installed express 3.x and the everyauth example is still using `app.dynamicHelpers` from express 2.x. Try again with express 2.x installed.

Specificaly [this line of code in everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/master/index.js#L56) calls `app.dynamicHelpers` which is an express 2.X API that does not exist in express 3.x. And [this line in the everyauth package.json](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/master/package.json#L39) further supports the notion that this example hasn't been updated for express 3.0.

The solution short term for you is:

```
npm uninstall express
npm install express@2.5.11
```

Long term, the everyauth example needs to be updated for the express 3.x API.

Comment: I didn't write any code myself. I am just trying to run the example of everyauth. So, is it that they have a bug in their code?